# Firebase Admin SDK sendMulticast

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

This code with a smaller list of tokens works correctly, but I don't know why it fails to send the notification to all the tokens when individually the token is valid.

I am doing something wrong? when the token list contains fewer tokens, all notifications are sent. There is a maximum of 30 tokens.

```
        let notificationData = {
            Id: messageInfo.ChatId,
            Type: notificationType.ChatMessage,
            Data: chatRoom
        };

        var payload = {
            notification: {
                title: title,
                body: body,
            },
            data: {
                NotificationData: JSON.stringify(notificationData),
            },
            apns: {
                payload: {
                    aps: {
                        sound: "default",
                    },
                },
            },
        };

        payload.tokens = chatRoom.FCMTokens;

        return admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload).then(response => {
            if (response.failureCount > 0) {
                const failedTokens = [];
                response.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
                    if (!resp.success) {
                        failedTokens.push(payload.tokens[idx]);
                    }
                });
                console.log('List of tokens that caused failures: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log('List of tokens that caused failures: ' + failedTokens);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Successsfully MulticastMessage");
            }
            return null;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error sending notification", error);
            return null;
        });
```

more info:

[image]
[image]

Comment: "This code with a smaller list of tokens works correctly, but I don't know why it fails to send the notification to all the tokens when individually the token is valid" - How do you know the individual tokens are valid? How are you validating them? [Tokens array containing null, empty string, or some other invalid item as default also makes the tokens invalid](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/985#issuecomment-670707493). Also if some of your tokens are not able to send notifications, what is the error code/message you are getting? Please provide these information.

Comment: because I send a notification to a token from that list and it arrives. directly enter

console.log ('List of tokens that caused failures:' + failedTokens);

Comment: Can you check if any empty string,null, invalid item/character is provided to the tokens as default values ? These can cause failing of the tokens. Also check for error messages in console if any.

Comment: It didn't provide any string or fault or null, it directly says that there has been a fault in all the tokens, I don't understand why. Then these same tokens (let's say 3) work when sending the multicast

Comment: If you can start a better chat

Comment: Can you change your payload to :  var payload = {
        notification: {
          title: title,
          body: messageText,
        },
        data: {
          messageID: messageID,
          messageTimestamp: messageTimestamp,
        },
        apns: {
          payload: {
            aps: {
              sound: "default",
            },
          },
        },
      };

Comment: but put sendMulticast?

Comment: Your code is fine. I just want you to change the payload structure to { notification: { title: title, body: messageText, }, data: { messageID: messageID, messageTimestamp: messageTimestamp, }, apns: { payload: { aps: { sound: "default", }, }, }, };  with rest of your code as it is. See this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66077010/15803365) where OP is facing a similar issue. The code is more or less like yours. I am sure this will help you.

Comment: Any update? Did you change the code according to the thread? Did it work?

Comment: I have edited my question. It still doesn't work and I don't understand why

Comment: Can you console.log(JSON.stringify(response)) like this ? :- return admin
          .messaging()
          .sendMulticast(payload)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(
              "Sent filtered message (using sendMulticast) notification: ",
              JSON.stringify(response)
            );

Comment: I have re-edited my question, I think something from the sdk is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240716/discussion-between-angelru-and-priyashree-bhadra).

Comment: Yes we can do that. But you got me wrong I wanted you to console.log( JSON.stringify(response) after this line " return admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload).then(response => {" and before "if (response.failureCount > 0) {"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that being many users in the payload exceeded 4kb

Notification messages can contain an optional data payload. Maximum payload for both message types is 4KB, except when sending messages from the Firebase console, which enforces a 1024 character limit.